# Integrate a discrete function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

how to know if you can integrate this function:

$$
   f(x) = 
     \begin{cases}
       1 & : \frac{1}{x},\ x \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \\
       0 & : \text{otherwise}
     \end{cases}
$$

Over the range $[0,1]$.

For me, since the range is not in $\mathbb{R}$, this is not integrable.

Comment: Which kind of integral do you use? With Lebesgue integration it is integrable with $\int f=0$ since $f=0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Well, in the range $[0,1]$ the function is zero everywhere except for $x=1$, so it is Riemann integrable with integral zero.

Comment: I am presuming that $\mathbb{Z}^+$ means $\{1,2,...\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $L(f,P) = 0$ for any partition of $[0,1]$.

Choose the partition $P_n=(0,1-{1 \over n}, 1)$, then $U(f,P) = {1 \over n}$.

Hence the Riemann integral of $f$ is 0.

Answer (score 0):

The integral of that function in any interval on even in the real line is 0. This is so because the support of the function, $\mathbb{Z}^+$ is a null set. In fact, you can compute

$$\int_{ \mathbb{R} } f = \int_{\mathbb{R}}  \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{ \chi_{\{ i \}}}{i} = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{ \chi_{\{ i \}}}{i}$$

Where you denote $\chi$ for the caracteristic function of a set. Of course the integral of $\chi_{\{ i \}}$ is zero, so the first integral is 0